# Shell script echo issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo

**In this if condition for shell script, i want print user full name + exist(if the file ..../pub_key.asc found)or not exist if the mentioned file not found**.

```
for file in $FILES
do
if [ -f  /home/$file/public_html/pub_key.asc ]; then
     echo $(cat /home/$file/etc/passwd | head -n | cut -d: -f1) : Exists
else
    echo  $(cat /home/$file/etc/passwd | head -n | cut -d: -f1) : Not exists!
fi
done
```

But i get errors because there is something wrong with first echo in if..condition.
Can someone show tell me what i did worng in the echo statement? and how to fix? appreciate your suggestions. :)

Comment: You appear to be using `[ ... ]` in place of a command substitution `$(...)`; it's not clear why.

Comment: i made this change with braces such $(...)  but still same problem

Comment: What error, exactly?  What is the value of `FILES`?

Comment: Why would there be a file `etc/passwd` in the user's home directory?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want something like `grep "$file" /etc/passwd`?

Comment: Bamar.. thx but i made the change and the output was wrong also.

Comment: chepner..  Error message in Norwegian, but its says for every shown user.                  
cut: /home/240379/etc/passwd: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog .....(no such file or folder)
grep: 1: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog .....(not such file or folder)

cut: /home/240380/etc/passwd: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog......(no such file or folder)
grep: 1: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog ......(no such file or folder)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting an error due to *head -n* command

*head -n* has to be followed by a number, e.g *head -n 1*, or *head -1*

Comment: i changed it, but it appear now another error message its says for every shown user. cut: /home/240379/etc/passwd: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog .....(no such file or folder) grep: 1: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog .....(not such file or folder) cut: /home/240380/etc/passwd: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog......(no such file or folder) grep: 1: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog ......(no such file or folder)

Comment: ok, so file /home/240379/etc/passwd does not exist.. perhaps the info you need is in file /etc/passwd, as already mentioned by @Barmar